# Database table row prevention for multiple users access

Tags: database, spring, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL with java spring application and requirement is , if any row in table access by any user then if same time another user will try to access the same row then this user will get a alert like this row is already using by someone.

So please any one let me know where I need to work to achieve this, means

a) Database level

or

b) My spring java application level.

If you have any idea about this requirement please share to me.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You may read similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877299/preventing-simultaneous-db-table-row-access

Comment: Do you really want to avoid two users from reading the same row? May be you are looking for serializable isolation level. Please see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html and serializable level section under that. Do ensure you understand the implications of setting isolation level at serializable.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Postgresql Explicit Locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html), maybe `Row-level Locks` section help to you.

Comment: Ok , Are you have any example or sample  ,this link seem like table lable lock

Answer (score 0):

While in a transaction, you can do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to lock a row (or rows) involved in your query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE YOUR_CONDITION
   FOR UPDATE
   NOWAIT -- THIS IS OPTIONAL
```

If you add `NOWAIT` clause (as shown above), it will raise an exception if the row is already been locked by other transaction.

Other wise, it will wait (and freeze) until the other lock release it self (by commiting/rollbacking the transaction) and this query will accquire a new lock.